# Explain and/or fix iBook/iPad sync problem

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, books

[According to Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202075),

> You can also add PDFs to your iTunes library on your computer by
>   dragging and dropping the PDF into your iTunes Book library. The files
>   will appear when you are preparing your device to sync.

I have also done this in the past with epubs from non-Apple sources.  But for nearly a year, I can't do it.  There are several possibly related issues:

1. In iTunes, the PDFs and pubs I have added recently do not appear in the checklist of items available to sync.  Those added before the problem started still appear.  I have sorted by date, title, and author and can't see them.  I look in iBooks and verify they are there.
2. There is at least one book for which there is **one** copy in iBook on the MacBook, but iTunes says there are two.  Checking them both makes two copies on the iPad.
3. If I select only PDF in iTunes, it says there are **none**. But there are many on each device.
4. At least two items that are **already** on the iPad are not checked in iTunes.

I can mail things to myself, and "open in iBooks" on the iPad, but that's a bit of proctalgia.  If I turn on "save to iCloud," items are automatically on both, but only that ones that go up first, because my space fills up.  And I don't get to decide which ones go first.

I can use Microsoft One-Drive or Dropbox, but either one is a nuisance (and OneDrive is unreliable).

I looked at all the items with pertinent-sounding titles in the suggestions and in the similar items, but none are duplicate.  A couple of them are related but aren't quite duplicate and certainly don't help.

Comment: Can you please clarify what your actual question is?  Please review [ask] and [What not to ask](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for assistance in formulating your question.

Comment: oops.  I wiped out the question when I edited.  Fixed.